# Spring Boot with Oauth2

Tags: angularjs, spring, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I developed a Google OAuth2 Login in Spring Boot and its working fine. I want to redirect to some specific URL after a button has been clicked. I am using an `application.yml` with  Google Oauth2.

I want to redirect to a specific URL after my authentification.

Here is the code I use for Google OAuth2:

### **Application.yml**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: <Google Client Id>
      clientSecret: <Google Secret Id>
      accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope:
        - openid
        - email
        - profile
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
      preferTokenInfo: true
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code?

Comment: This code is fine. I want to redirect it to some other page

Comment: You want to change the url you're redirected to after the login process?

Comment: I want to make one Html in which when I will login it will do the Oauth autentiction and redirect to some specific URL here in this code I uses Google API but my actual requirement is that one

Comment: The flow for OAuth authentication should be: user requests some url -> if you don't have authorization the server redirects to login page -> the original url is served. Maybe what you want is to modify the first access: ex. user requests `/` and you redirect to `/home.html`. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43697207/1199132

Comment: In the authorize request towards Google, you should add the redirect_uri parameter.

Comment: u need to add redirect_uri:{your-redirect-uri} to your request

Answer (score 0):

In the authorize request towards Google, you should add the `redirect_uri` parameter

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        clientId: <Google Client Id>
        clientSecret: <Google Secret Id>
        redirectUri: https://YOUR_REDIRECT_URL // *** here ***
        accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
        userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
        clientAuthenticationScheme: form
        scope:
          - openid
          - email
          - profile
      resource:
        userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
        preferTokenInfo: true
```